# Change text color in baseadapter getview on button click

Tags: android

Good day to all 
Is it possible to change text color of `Textview` in the Row which inflated by base adapter with click on button in the activity. I need to change text color on button click.

**MainActivity.class**

```
Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);            }
    });

Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);            }
    });
```

**Adapter.class**

```
public class Adaptor extends BaseAdapter {
TextView tvtitle;
Context context;
private int textSize;



public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <Item> List ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = List;
}

ArrayList <Item> List;


@Override
public int getCount () {

    returnList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {

    return List.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout, null);
    }
    Item currentNews = List.get(position);
    tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);
    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    return convertView;
}
```

**newsitemlist_layout.xml**

```
RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="News TITLE"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: All of the rows should change color, or a specific row?

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: all row means complete listview

Answer (score 1):

assign color to an object on button click and call`adpater.notifyDataSetChanged()`
and in your adapter getView() method set textcolor from that object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set color in adapter for each row, then if button clicks change color in adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(). It will apply changed color to all rows.

I modified your code

```
Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            adapter.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()            }
    });

Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            adapter.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()           }
    });
```

and in your adapter

```
public class Adaptor extends BaseAdapter {
TextView tvtitle;
Context context;
private int textSize;
private int color;



public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <Item> List ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = List;
    this.color = Color.RED   //default color
}

ArrayList <Item> List;


@Override
public int getCount () {

    returnList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {

    return List.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout, null);
    }
    Item currentNews = List.get(position);
    tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);
    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    tvtitle.setColor(color);
    return convertView;
}

public void setTextColor(int color){
    this.color = color;
}
```

Comment: Asad Brother Thank you.Allah bless you